# Loading AngularJS views using partials or inline code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

The documentation of Ionic Framework states the following:

> Pages are loaded by the URLs given. One simple way to create templates in Angular is to put them directly into your HTML file and use the `<script type="text/ng-template">` syntax. This is good to do because the template will be cached for very fast loading, instead of having to fetch them from the network.

In the AngularJS documentation I find following statement:

> To add the detailed view, we could expand the index.html file to contain template code for both views, but that would get messy very quickly. Instead, we are going to turn the index.html template into what we call a "layout template". This is a template that is common for all views in our application. Other "partial templates" are then included into this layout template depending on the current "route" — the view that is currently displayed to the user.

With other words, Ionic documentation says that loading in templates via the script tags is way more effecient than via seperate partials. My question is: is there a significant difference in performance for my mobile applications? I rather prefer a good overview but if that comes with less performance for my apps, I would rather use partials.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the best of both worlds by adding [grunt-angular-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates) to your build process. During development time you can organize your code using partials and at build time all partials are included in your main JavaScript application file.